# Compile a program with opencv and query (to my database) codes

Tags: c++, mysql, c, opencv

I wrote a program with openCv libraries and compile it with pkg_config as I mentioned below:

g++ imageproc.cpp -o imageproc `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`

now I must check a flag in my Database for run some functions in my program So I write some query to MySQL server. the problem is that I don't know how I must compile the program. previously I compile programs with query in this way:

gcc funcname.c -o funcname `mysql_config --cflags --libs`

Can any body help me to compile this program (which has opencv codes and query command)?

Thanks in Advnce.

Comment: Is your problem related to C or to C++?

Comment: what you mean? In C programming No but I think most of C expert can help me.

Comment: C and C++ are not the same languages and the compilation process, while similar, holds differences too. Please be specific as to what your problem is, what it is related to, and more importantly: tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs

Comment: ok, let me say my problem in other words. I have a main program in C++ language but in this program I must sometimes query to MySQL server so it has some query command too. now I'm confused that how I can compile it? :(

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](//stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am surprised. I saw some simple and ordinary question in stackoverflow that was answered with lot experts patiently. But I don't know why I fail again..

Comment: Your question lacks a demonstration of what is really causing you problem. SO is not here to tell you how to do stuff you didn't even try, it's here to help you understand why you failed and how to correct *your* work. Research, try it, maybe you will succeed, but if you don't : come back here and update the question with what went wrong